# I am trying to override core interface in Vendor\magento\sales\Api\Data\OrderItemInterface.php

Tags: database, api, overrides, interface

My di.xml code is here, is there any alternative way to override an interface for core file.

```
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemInterface"
type="Vendor\Name\Api\Data\OrderItemInterface" />
```

Answer (score 2):

> Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemInterface

Is **a service provider data**   interface which already rewritten it  by  `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item`, as per as [Magento 2 service contact](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/architecture/archi_perspectives/service_layer.html)

```
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemInterface" type="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item"/>
```

Please take look at [di.xml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/Sales/etc/di.xml#L24) of Sales module, You can understand.

**It means you have to try to override the same interface so, it is not working.**

I guess you want to modify this class to add a new field. So, in this case, i am suggesting to you implement extension attribute

Check out how to  below blog how to implement below blogs for

https://www.zynovo.com/blog/magento-2-extension-attributes/

https://www.interactiv4.com/e-commerce-en/extension-attributes-codehacks-i4/?lang=en